# How to check the values of checkpoints?

Tags: tensorflow

How can we check that the checkpoint is restored correctly and how we can check the values of the weights in checkpoints. I am working in tensorflow 2.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you have a `tf.keras.Model` object called `model`, you can call `model.layers[0].get_weights()` to get the weights of the first layer.

Comment: Thank you . It was helpful and now I can see the output of first layer but I would like to know that how can we say that the results of the layer are right , I mean the model has learnt and the results are not having any garbage values.